# Does Equestria have elections?

Tags: my-little-pony-fim, my-little-pony, politics

The country of Equestria in *My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic* seems to be a dual monarchy (or, if you want to be strict with language, a principality) ruled by Princesses Celestia and Luna (with a period of sole rule by Celestia during Luna's exile).

Does Equestria have meaningful elections of any kind at any level (e.g. a legislative assembly, citizens' advisory council, etc.)? The town of Ponyville seems to have a Mayor, which, in English speaking countries, is typically an elected office, and she acts more like a politician than an aristocrat, but I don't recall any specific mention of anyone who either did or did not vote for her (so it's not clear if she was elected by the citizens, was appointed by Celestia, or inherited her office).

Comment: There's a bunch of stuff here that you might find useful. They appears to have an elected hereditary monarchy https://www.reddit.com/r/mylittlepony/comments/3yncyp/what_type_of_government_is_equestria/ plus a bunch of minor democratic elements like a mayor and councils.

Comment: They have elections for trivial roles; http://mlp.wikia.com/wiki/The_Vote

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you consider to be canon material.

You mentioned Mayor Mare. In the comics, there is a full two parts story arc revolving an attempt to overthrow her.
The story is called Elections and it spans issues [#46](http://mlp.wikia.com/wiki/Election#Issue_.2346) and [#47](http://mlp.wikia.com/wiki/Election#Issue_.2347) of the IDW "My Little Pony: Friendship Is Magic" comic series.

From the wikia:

> Election is the sixteenth story arc of IDW Publishing's comic series, spanning issues #46 and #47. In the story, Filthy Rich runs against Mayor Mare for mayor of Ponyville, sparking the town's first election to occur in years.

The comic also featured multiple covers variants, each one portraying a different candidate in the election.

As far as the main show goes... there haven't been any real proof of actual elections. The closest thing is various rulers being recognized as such for various reasons:

- Celestia and Luna were basically "elected" by the three tribes after the Windingo incident. This is referenced in the Journal of the Two Sisters (probably no longer canon after S7 finale) and is also somehow implied in the show.
- the reformed changeling have accepted the current ruler as their leader
- probably the same could be said about the dragons and the Dragon Lord title (it isn't clear if the staff had any actual power or is just a symbol)
- we know nothing about the yaks.